# Using tidyverse to get raw_alpha values with the psych package from different datasets / databases

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, psych

I spent one day looking for this answer and I'm almost giving up. Actually, I really imagine is a pretty simple situation, but I'll be glad of any help.

Let's say **I have two datasets**, the first get all ID of all students

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

ds_of_students <- data.frame(id=(1:4), school=c("public","private"))
```

The second one has all the results of a test. Let's say **each column is an ID**.

```
ds_of_results <- structure(list(i1 = c(1, 2, 4, 4),
                                i2 = c(3, 3, 2, 2),
                                i3 = c(2, 3, 3, 5),
                                i4 = c(4, 1, 3, 2)), 
                           class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                     "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

And now I need to report a table of students ID , groupped by school, and they results (Actually, It's a Cronbach alpha results, what is pretty common in Psychology).

```
ds_of_students %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarise(n=n(), 
            id = paste(id, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(item2=psych::alpha(ds_of_results[c(id)])$total[1])
```

I've got this message

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Columns `2,4`, `1,3` not found.
```

But When I run in the traditional fashion, it works

```
psych::alpha(ds_of_results[c(1,3)])$total[1]
```

I've tried to work with paste, [noquote](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/262870.html), [gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681952/removing-replacing-brackets-from-r-string-using-gsub) ans [strcol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679510/r-dplyr-get-variable-name-as-string-in-mutate-summarise)

Please, run this code to have reproducible results. Thanks much!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)
ds_of_students <- data.frame(id=(1:4), school=c("public","private"))
ds_of_results <- structure(list(i1 = c(1, 2, 4, 4),
                                i2 = c(3, 3, 2, 2),
                                i3 = c(2, 3, 3, 5),
                                i4 = c(4, 1, 3, 2)), 
                           class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                     "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ds_of_students %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarise(n=n(), 
            id = paste(id, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(item2=psych::alpha(ds_of_results[c(id)])$total[1])


alpha(ds_of_results[c(1,3)])$total[1]
```

My desired output is something like that
[image: Desired output]

And just to give some reality to my question, that's the real dataset, where I have to compute the Cronbach's alpha item the items of each group.

[image: Real results]

Comment: Can you also provide your desired result for this example?

Comment: when you paste, you're creating a character vector. You can't pass the string "2,4" as a subset call and expect to get the same result as passing the two integers.

Comment: @iod Please, take a look at the new code. I've added an image and changed the code to make my question clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
get_alpha <- function(x) {  
  raw_alpha <-
    psych::alpha(
      ds_of_results[, ds_of_students[ds_of_students$school == x, 1]])$total[1]
  ids <-
    paste0(names(ds_of_results[, ds_of_students[ds_of_students$school == x, 1]]),
           collapse = ",")
  data.frame(
    school = x,
    id = ids,
    raw_alpha = raw_alpha
  )
}

map_df(levels(ds_of_students$school), get_alpha)
```

Result

```
   school    id raw_alpha
1 private i2,i4      0.00
2  public i1,i3      0.85
```

There were several issues in your code:

- `mutate` uses variables within a data frame while `psych::alpha` needs entire data frames. So I don't think that you can get your alpha values with mutate
- you use `$total` to extract one element of the list of data frames given by `psych::alpha`, but that does not work in a pipeline (the pipe does not handle lists and only works with data frames)

So basically, `psych::alpha`, which needs entire data frames as input and outputs a list of data frames does not play well with a classic `dplyr` wrangling workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but try this and tell me if you're getting the expected result. Replace your `summarise` call like this (also note the "unlist" in the mutate call):

```
ds_of_students %>% mutate(id=lapply(strsplit(id,","),as.integer))
    group_by(school) %>%
    summarise(id = list(id)) %>% 
mutate(item2=psych::alpha(ds_of_results[unlist(id)])$total[1])
```

What I'm doing here is replacing your paste with a list, so that the numbers are retained as numbers, and can be passed to the subset call in the next step without a hitch. This will also work if id is a character, of course, assuming the column names in ds_of_results are the id's from ds_of_students. You need to pass it with `unlist` so that the subset gets it as a simple vector, rather than as a list with one vector element.

With your fake data, I get this error:

```
Some items ( i2 i4 ) were negatively correlated with the total scale and 
probably should be reversed.  
To do this, run the function again with the 'check.keys=TRUE' option# A tibble: 2 x 3
  school  id        item2       
  <fct>   <list>    <data.frame>
1 private <int [2]> -1          
2 public  <int [2]> -1          
Warning messages:
1: In cor.smooth(r) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
2: In psych::alpha(ds_of_results[unlist(id)]) :
  Some items were negatively correlated with the total scale and probably 
should be reversed.  
To do this, run the function again with the 'check.keys=TRUE' option
3: In cor.smooth(R) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
4: In cor.smooth(R) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
```

But that might just be a problem with the fake data itself, not the code.

Comment: Thanks, in my real dataset, I've got this result:
`k %>%
  group_by(Fator) %>%
  summarise(Qtde=n(), 
            item = paste(item, collapse = ","), 
            item = list(item),
            Min=round(min(Carga),2), 
            Max=round(max(Carga),2)) %>% 
  mutate(item2=psych::alpha(items_a[unlist(item)])$total[1])`

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Columns `9,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25`, `1,12,13,30`, `31,32,33`, `2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11`, `36,37,38`, `28,39,40,41` not found.`

Comment: Are all these columns actually in `items_a`? Can you give me the result of `names(items_a)`?

Comment: Sure,   ` items_a %>% names()
 [1] "i1"  "i2"  "i3"  "i4"  "i5"  "i6"  "i7"  "i8"  "i9"  "i10" "i11" "i12" "i13" "i14" "i15" "i16" "i17" "i18" "i19" "i20"
[21] "i21" "i22" "i23" "i24" "i25" "i26" "i27" "i28" "i29" "i30" "i31" "i32" "i33" "i34" "i35" "i36" "i37" "i38" "i39" "i40"
[41] "i41 ` 
I changed the fake code to make it easier to understand. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I see the problem now - `item` in your actual data is not an integer but a string, so we again have the same problem. Insert this line before you `group_by(Fator)` call: `mutate(item=lapply(strsplit(item,","),as.integer))`. Also, remove the `item = paste(item, collapse = ",")` from your `summarise`.

Comment: Thanks much for your support!! I'll try it and let you know the results!! =) =)